# Kendo UI Grid export to CSV and download for filtered and sorted result for all pages

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have implemented the kendo grid in our application. It has functionality sort, filter, paging, and search. I am trying to download kendo grid result as CSV after we perform the sort, filter and search actions. I need to download all the pages of kendo grid. For that, I have passed the kendo request as JSON string on form submission and then tried to deserialize the JSON string as kendorequest on action controller. I could see the filtered request is not getting on the controller.
I have used following jquery code.

```
var grid = $("#Grid").data("kendoGrid"); 
var parameterMap = grid.dataSource.transport.parameterMap;
var sortData = grid.dataSource.sort();
var filterData = grid.dataSource.filter();
var groupData = grid.dataSource.group();
var prepared = parameterMap({ sort: sortData, filter: filterData, group: groupData });      
var jsonString = JSON.stringify({ request: prepared });
postToUrl(actionurl, { jsonString: jsonString }, "post");


function postToUrl(path, params, method) {
    method = method || "post";
    $("#tempForm").remove();
    var form = document.createElement("form");
    form.setAttribute("method", method);
    form.setAttribute("action", path);
    form.setAttribute("id", "tempForm");

    for (var key in params) {
        if (params.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            var hiddenField = document.createElement("input");
            hiddenField.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
            hiddenField.setAttribute("name", key);
            hiddenField.setAttribute("value", params[key]);
            form.appendChild(hiddenField);
        }
    }    
    document.body.appendChild(form);
    form.submit();
}
```

I tried to get the kendo request on the below action controller. Also, this controller has the source code to export and download the grid as a CSV file based on the Kendo request.

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult ExportCustomerLookUpGrid(string jsonString)
    {        
            var myDetails = JObject.Parse(jsonString);            
            JToken requestJToken = myDetails["request"];        
            var request = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataSourceRequest>(requestJToken.ToString());

            string SQLWhereCondition = GenerateSQlquery(request);
            var dtresults = getAge(SQLWhereCondition);

            ExportDataTableAsExcel(dtresults, Response, "CustomerData", model.DownloadToken);
            return Json(false, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);      
    }
```

Can anyone help to get the kendo request on action controller when we passed it from client-side?